# Is it possible to create backup jobs on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with SMO

Tags: backup, smo, sql-server-2008r2-express, maintenance-plan

In our software because the users are using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, I would want to create backup jobs for them programmatically using the SMO API. Is it possible? If possible point me to any articles written on this light of this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Express versions don't have the SQL Server Agent that executes jobs - no, I don't think this is possible.

What you *could* do however is create a standalone console app that uses the SMO library to perform the SQL Server backup, and then just schedule that console app on your machine using the built-in Windows scheduler, to runonce every day (or every four hours or whatever you need)

As for resources on SMO - check these out:

- [Getting started with SMO in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=37)
- [Using SMO for Backup, Restore and Security Purposes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14848/Using-SMO-for-Backup-Restore-and-Security-Purposes)